# Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at runtime

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use JNI to access C++ methods from a Java class. I'm able to compile (both in Eclipse or on command line) my Java class fine, but on executing the class at runtime, I'm getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.domain.services.CallServiceAPIS.createSession()I
>       at com.domain.services.CallServiceAPIS.createSession(Native Method)
>       at com.domain.services.CallServiceAPIS.main(CallServiceAPIS.java:18)

Java code is as follows:

```
package com.domain.services;

public class CallServiceAPIS {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("service.client");
    }

    public native int createSession();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        new CallServiceAPIS().createSession();
    }
}
```

I included the printout of the java.library.path just to make sure it's pointing to the correct location of the C++ library - and it is. I also tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my Eclipse environment. But neither worked.

Note that the System.loadLibrary call IS working since 1) the code compiles and 2) the error occurs on line 18, which is the new CallServiceAPIs call.

C++ code:

```
 int createSession(const PosServiceInfo info, const SessionArgs& args, Domain::UUID& uuidSession)
    {
        return int::undefined;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show C++ source code where createSession is defined.

Comment: @gudok added C++ source

Comment: `return int::undefined;`  -- This is not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I realized that I was using the JNI interface incorrectly. I was thinking you could load an EXISTING C++ library using EXISTING C++ source. But you basically have to rewrite the existing code to make use of the JNI interface.

Comment: It may be easier to use jna instead of raw jni (at the cost of performance penalty).

Comment: @gudok Thanks, will try that.